# Problema de selección de dates Bootstrap Range Picker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy utililizando este plugin

> http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Elaboré este código que básicamente recoge el la fecha que está arrojando el input y la mete a un div en forma de lista, cuando le doy click al item, lo quito de la lista.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateRange_high" readonly>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.removeItem',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});

  function parseDate(date) {
    var parseDate = date.split("-");
    return new Date(parseDate[0], parseDate[1] - 1, parseDate[2]);
  }

  function daydiff(firstDate, secondDate) {
    return Math.round((secondDate - firstDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }
  $("#dateRange_high").daterangepicker({
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "startDate": "07/01/2017",
    "endDate": "07/01/2017",
    "minDate": "07/01/2017",
    "maxDate": "06/30/2018",
    "applyClass": "btn-info"
  }, function(start, end) {
    $("#well_high ol").append("<li class='removeItem' style='cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;'>del <label class='dateStart'>" + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "</label> al <label class='dateEnd'>" + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') +
      "</label>, días tomados <b>" + daydiff(parseDate(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')), parseDate(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))) + "</b></li>");
    if ($("#well_high").height() > 500) {
      $("#well_high").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
      $("#well_high").css("max-height", 500);
    }
  });
</script>
<div class="well well-lg" id="well_high">
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```

El problema viene cuando deseo volver a escoger la misma fecha que quité, no me deja. Por ejemplo agarro el rango 2017-06-08 al 2017-06-10 y la agrega bien al la lista, pero si la quito y voy a la consola de desarrolladores no está ya el elemento, pero el plugin no me deja volver a escoger el mismo rango de fechas.

Es un bug o que le falta a mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia $(this).remove(); por $(this).hide(); para que no se elimine de la lista:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeItem',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

y para que se vuelvan a mostrar:

```
$(document).on('click','#dateRange_high',function(){
    $('. removeItem').show();
});
```

suerte...

Comment: El problema es que al terminar la captura voy a recorrer todos esos LI y sacar las labels para ingresarlas en la DB, Si lo oculto como propones toda esa información que va a guardar aunque el usuario ya no la quiera. Igual agradezco tu respuesta.